# How to get the current active swiper image src and set it in another image?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, swiper.js

I'm using swiper js and I'm trying to get the src of the current active swiper image's src and set it to an image src which is not related to the swiper, so that whenever I click on the next or previous buttons It renders the same as swiper current active image.

The code in jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fateh_alrabeai/yrtvogbn/35/

The HTML Code:

```
<!--The image I want to be set it's soursce from the current active swiper image-->
<div class="crrent-image" id="crrent-image" style="text-align:center;">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="currentImage" alt="">
</div>

<!--swiper code -->
  <div class="swiper-container gallery-top" style="margin-top:15px;">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide" >
         <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      
      <div class="swiper-slide" >
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" >
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" >
         <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
   
      
    </div>
    <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="swiper-container gallery-thumbs">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide" >
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg)"></div>
  

  </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      slidesPerView: 4,
      freeMode: true,
      watchSlidesVisibility: true,
      watchSlidesProgress: true,
    });
    var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
      thumbs: {
        swiper: galleryThumbs
      }
    });
    
$(document).ready(function() { 
      
            var currentImage = $('.swiper-slide img').attr(src);
            // console.log(var1);
            $('#crrent-image img').attr('src', currentImage);
      
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone was looking for the same answer.

This is how I solved it :

```
$(".swiper-button-next").click(function() {
             var currentActiveSlide = $('.swiper-slide-active img').attr('src');

            $('#main_image img').attr('src', currentActiveSlide);
        });
 $(".swiper-button-prev").click(function() {
            var currentActiveSlide = $('.swiper-slide-active img').attr('src');

            $('#main_image img').attr('src', currentActiveSlide);
        });
```